# Read all HTTP URLs from PCAp file

Tags: wireshark, pcap

I try to get Read all HTTP URLs from PCAp file using this command line command:

```
tshark -R -e http.request.uri -r C:file.pcap
```

And got the message

```
tshark: -R without -2 is deprecated. For single-pass filtering use -Y.
```

What's wrong with my filter ?

Answer (score 2):

Using the filter as single pass, like suggested, does it for me:

```
tshark -Y http.request.uri -r capturefile
```